# in this both the function why it is require to do WATCHDOG_RESET()?

Tags: c, linux

```
    void NS16550_putc(NS16550_t com_port, char c)
    {
        while ((serial_in(&com_port->lsr) & UART_LSR_THRE) == 0);
    //write to the THR 
        serial_out(c, &com_port->thr);
        if (c == '\n')
    //why do we require to call this watch dog reset
        WATCHDOG_RESET();
    }
```

---

```
    char NS16550_getc(NS16550_t com_port)
    {
        while ((serial_in(&com_port->lsr) & UART_LSR_DR) == 0) {    
    #ifdef CONFIG_USB_TTY    
        extern void usbtty_poll(void);    
        usbtty_poll();    
    #endif
    //why do we require to call this watch dog reset
        WATCHDOG_RESET();    
    }
    //return the rbr value 
        return serial_in(&com_port->rbr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the context of this code.

But most likely it's because you don't want your operation to last so long that the watchdog times out (and resets your device...)

for example,

```
while ((serial_in(&com_port->lsr) & UART_LSR_DR) == 0) {    
    #ifdef CONFIG_USB_TTY    
        extern void usbtty_poll(void);    
        usbtty_poll();    
    #endif
    //why do we require to call this watch dog reset
        WATCHDOG_RESET();    
    }
```

In the above code, you're validating some condition repeatedly in this while loop, now this loop may run for a long time and if you don't reset your watchdog timer (or kick your watchdog), the watchdog'll likely time out eventually.

Comment: but every time condition in while loop is satisfy device will be reset?